# SP2010 Custom Workflow - validate checkbox

Tags: designer-workflow

I am trying to create a custom workflow that checks to see if "**All Day Event**" is checked but cannot seem to create the proper Condition in SPD.

I have `If CurrentItem:AllDayEvent contains "Yes"`

I have also tried `If CurrentItem:AllDayEvent contains Yes` (without quotes around Yes)...

```
If CurrentItem:AllDayEvent is not empty
If CurrentItem:AllDayEvent equals "Yes"
```

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding it to the workflow?

1. add the "`If current item field equals value`" condition
2. set the "`field`" option to the check-box field
3. the "`value`" option should let you pick between "**Yes**" or "**No**"

[image]

Comment: That is the condition that I used but it does not give me the Yes/No option. I can change "equals" to a variety of options then when I click on "value" I can create a string.

Comment: It may help to mention that this is a default column on the Event content type for calendars.

Comment: Does it work if you use equals 1?